# accessing individual elements from a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a data which has been generated dynamically. The output of the data looks like this and it is of dictionary type.

```
dict_items([('date', ['2011-10-31', '2012-05-08']), 

('status', ['completed', 'completed']), 

('id', ['18', '12']) ])
```

I need to access these data and insert it into the database dynamically.

How to get this into a structure which can be used to insertion operation?
I am not sure of how to proceed after this. can someone suggest me a possible way of insertion into a database.

I want the structure to look like this:

```
{ {date,status,id},{'2011-10-31','completed','18'},
{date,status,id},{'2011-05-08','completed','12'}}
```

Comment: you cant have a structure like `{ {date,status,id},{'2011-10-31','completed','18'},{date,status,id},{'2011-05-08','completed','12'}}` Its neither a dict nor a list

Comment: Then can you please tell me how the struture will look like

Comment: @AshokaLella: but it *is* a **set**. You cannot have (mutable) sets in side another set, but you can use `frozenset()` to get essentially the same.

Comment: What you have is **not** a dictionary, however. You have the result of calling [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), which is a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). It may be that you expected sets, however. Presumably your original dictionary was `{'date': ['2011-10-31', '2012-05-08'], 'id': ['18', '12'], 'status': ['completed', 'completed']}`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, my bad, never came across such data structure

Comment: Your output structure doesn't make much sense, however, perhaps you wanted `[{'date': '2011-10-31', 'status': 'completed', 'id': '18'}, {'date': '2011-05-08', 'status': 'completed', 'id': '12'}]` instead? E.g. a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to output a list of **dictionaries**, one for each 'column' in the values, you can use `zip()` to transform the values into grouped columns:

```
keys = yourdict.keys()
output = [dict(zip(keys, col)) for col in zip(*yourdict.values())]
```

Demo:

```
>>> yourdict = {'date': ['2011-10-31', '2012-05-08'], 'id': ['18', '12'], 'status': ['completed', 'completed']}
>>> keys = yourdict.keys()
>>> [dict(zip(keys, col)) for col in zip(*yourdict.values())]
[{'date': '2011-10-31', 'id': '18', 'status': 'completed'}, {'date': '2012-05-08', 'id': '12', 'status': 'completed'}]
```

If you really wanted to output interleaved sets of keys, then values, you can do:

```
keys = set(yourdict.keys())
output = [elem for col in zip(*yourdict.values()) for elem in (keys, set(col))]
```

which results in:

```
>>> keys = set(yourdict.keys())
>>> [elem for col in zip(*yourdict.values()) for elem in (keys, set(col))]
[{'date', 'id', 'status'}, {'completed', '2011-10-31', '18'}, {'date', 'id', 'status'}, {'2012-05-08', 'completed', '12'}]
```

Note that I used a list here, not an (outer) set, as that'd not allow for multiple `{'date', 'id', 'status'}` sets; values in a set are unique, after all.

Answer (score 0):

to some extend to update mysql  below format may be sufficient

```
t=[('date', ['2011-10-31', '2012-05-08']),

('status', ['completed', 'completed']),

('id', ['18', '12']) ]

dic={i[0]:i[1] for i in t}
lis=[]
for i,j,k in zip(*dic.values()):
    lis.append((i,j,k))


print lis
#[('2011-10-31', 'completed', '18'), ('2012-05-08', 'completed', '12')]
```

Comment: For the record, this is *probably* Python 3, where `dict.items()` returns a `dict_items()` dictionary view. In Python 2 you'd call `dict.viewitems()`, but fewer people stumble upon that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i donnot know  that . thanks

Comment: Ah, I missed something in the requirements of the OP here. You can use `zip(*list_of_lists)` to transpose rows to columns.